# ¿Cómo unir dataframes con distinto número de columnas con rbind?

Tags: r, rstudio, join, dplyr

Tengo los siguientes data frame.

```
set.seed(23)
df2<-data.frame(a=sample(1:10, 5), b=sample(c("A","B","C","D"),5, T))
set.seed(22)
df3<-data.frame(a=sample(10:20, 5), b=sample(c("A","B","C","D"),5, T),
                d=sample(1:100,5))

   df2
   a b
   8 C
   3 A
  10 B
   1 D
   9 A

   df3
   a b  d
  15 D 67
  18 D 48
  17 C 16
  11 A 58
  20 A 72
```

Deseo juntarlos con un `rbind`, pero como es obvio no se puede porque el `df3` tiene 3 columnas y el `df2` sólo 2.

¿Cómo podría hacer para juntarlos sin crear la columna `d` en el `df2`?. Ya que en mi problema real la diferencia entre columnas no sólo es de una sino de 47 columnas.

Entiendo que tampoco se puede hacer con los joins del paquete `dplyr` ya que si tomaría como llave la columna `a` habría ambiguedad en la columna `b` y el software pondría `b.x` y `b.y`. Saldría así:

```
full_join(df2,df3, by="a")
    a  b.x  b.y  d
    8    C <NA> NA
    3    A <NA> NA
   10    B <NA> NA
    1    D <NA> NA
    9    A <NA> NA
   15 <NA>    D 67
   18 <NA>    D 48
   17 <NA>    C 16
   11 <NA>    A 58
   20 <NA>    A 72
```

Puedo considerar usar la llave por `a` y `b`. Así:

```
full_join(df2,df3, by=c("a","b"))
    a b  d
    8 C NA
    3 A NA
   10 B NA
    1 D NA
    9 A NA
   15 D 67
   18 D 48
   17 C 16
   11 A 58
   20 A 72
```

Que me sale lo que deseo. Pero un detalle más es que como la columna `b` tengo 22 columnas. Así que colocar las 22 columnas en el `join` no me parece eficiente.

Creo que el `rbind` es la mejor opción, pero no veo cómo podría solucionar el distinto número de columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Al menos con los datos de ejemplo

```
dplyr::bind_rows(df2, df3)
```

da el resultado esperado. En la medida en que `df2` y `df3` no tengan columnas con igual nombre pero diferentes contenido (tipo) debería funcionar. De hecho también funciona `full_join(df2, df3)` sin el argumento `by`. Por defecto trata de hacer el join con todas columnas en común.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Había olvidado que los join de `dplyr` también funcionaban si omitías el by.

Answer (score 1):

Agrego [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46635610/6836377) que me parece muy ingeniosa usando solo R base:

```
df2[setdiff(names(df3), names(df2))] <- NA
df3[setdiff(names(df2), names(df3))] <- NA

rbind(df2, df3)
```

Básicamente se unifican las estructuras de los 2 `data.frames` para que sean consistentes para `rbind()`

Comment: Muchas gracias.